# Arbitrarily ordering records in a table

Tags: database-design, relational-theory, order-by, database-agnostic

A common need when using a database is to access records in order. For example, if I have a blog, I want to be able to reorder my blog posts in arbitrary order. These entries often have lots of relationships, so a relational database seems to make sense.

The common solution that I have seen is to add an integer column `order`:

```
CREATE TABLE AS your_table (id, title, sort_order)
AS VALUES
  (0, 'Lorem ipsum',   3),
  (1, 'Dolor sit',     2),
  (2, 'Amet, consect', 0),
  (3, 'Elit fusce',    1);
```

Then, we can sort the rows by `order` to get them in the proper order.

However, this seems clumsy:

- If I want to move record 0 to the start, I have to reorder every record
- If I want to insert a new record in the middle, I have to reorder every record after it
- If I want to remove a record, I have to reorder every record after it

It's easy to imagine a situations like:

- Two records have the same `order`
- There are gaps in the `order` between records

These could happen fairly easily for a number of reasons.

This is the approach that applications like Joomla take:

[image: Example of Joomla's approach to ordering]

You could argue that the interface here is bad, and that instead of humans directly editing numbers, they should use arrows or drag-and-drop—and you'd probably be right. But behind the scenes, the same thing is happening.

Some people have proposed using a decimal to store order, so that you can use "2.5" to insert a record in between the records at order 2 and 3. And while that helps a little, it's arguably even messier because you can end up with weird decimals (where do you stop? 2.75? 2.875? 2.8125?)

Is there a better way to store order in a table?

Comment: Just so you know . . . "The reason such systems are called "relational" is that the term *relation* is basically just a mathematical term for a *table* . . ." -- *An Introduction to Database Systems*, CJ Date, 7th ed. p 25

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Features and Patterns for Managing Ordered Lists](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176570/features-and-patterns-for-managing-ordered-lists)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' that I didn't catch, I've fixed the question with the old `orders` and ddl.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> If I want to move record 0 to the start, I have to reorder every record

No, there's a simpler way.

```
update your_table
set order = -1 
where id = 0;
```

> If I want to insert a new record in the middle, I have to reorder every record after it

That's true, unless you use a data type that supports "between" values. Float and numeric types allow you to update a value to, say, 2.5. But varchar(n) works, too.  (Think 'a', 'b', 'c'; then think 'ba', 'bb', 'bc'.)

> If I want to remove a record, I have to reorder every record after it

No, there's a simpler way. Just delete the row. The remaining rows will still sort correctly.

> It's easy to imagine a situations like:
>
> Two records have the same order

A unique constraint can prevent that.

> There are gaps in the order between records

Gaps have no effect on how a dbms sorts values in a column.

> Some people have proposed using a decimal to store order, so that you can use "2.5" to insert a record in between the records at order 2 and 3. And while that helps a little, it's arguably even messier because you can end up with weird decimals (where do you stop? 2.75? 2.875? 2.8125?)

You don't stop until you *have* to. The dbms has *no* problem sorting values that have 2, 7, or 15 places after the decimal point.

I think your *real* problem is that you'd like to *see* values in sorted order as integers. You can do that.

```
create table your_table (
  id int primary key, 
  title varchar(13), 
  sort_order float
);
    
insert into your_table values
(0, 'Lorem ipsum', 2.0),
(1, 'Dolor sit', 1.5),
(2, 'Amet, consect', 0.0),
(3, 'Elit fusce', 1.0);

-- This windowing function will "transform" the floats into sorted integers.
select id, title,
       row_number() over (order by sort_order)
from your_table
```

Comment: For the sake of neatness, you could finish the job with something like `with cte as (select *,row_number() over (order by sort_order desc) as row from test)
update cte set sort_order=row;`

Comment: Here is an additional hint:
If you want it to be really perfect, you should check if you're moving more rows then you wish to keep untouched. If so, then update the less numerous - the "untouched" - ones ;D

Answer (score 9):

It is very simple. You need to have a "cardinality hole" structure:

You need to have 2 columns:

1. pk = 32bit `integer`
2. order = 64bit `bigint` (**not** `double`)

#### Insert/update

1. When inserting the first new record, set `order = round(max_bigint / 2)`.
2. When inserting at the beginning of the table, set `order = round("order of first record" / 2)`
3. When inserting at the end of table, set `order = round("max_bigint - order of last record" / 2)`
   4) When inserting in the middle, set `order = round("order of record before - order of record after" / 2)`

This method has a very big cardinality. If you have constraint error or if you think what you have small cardinality you can rebuild order column (normalize).

In maximal situation with normalization (with this structure) you can have "cardinality hole" in 32 bit.

Remember not to use floating point types - order must be a precise value!

Answer (score 5):

Generally, ordering is done according to some information in the records, title, ID, or whatever is appropriate for that particular situation.

If you do need a special ordering, using an integer column isn't as bad as it might seem. For example, to make room for a record to go into 5th place, you could do something like:

`update table_1 set place = place + 1 where place > 5`.

Hopefully you can declare the column to be `unique` and maybe have a procedure to make rearrangements "atomic". The details depend on the system but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 4):

> …it's arguably even messier because you can end up with weird decimals (where do you stop? 2.75? 2.875? 2.8125?)

Who cares? These numbers are only there for the computer to deal with so it doesn't matter how many fractional digits they have or how ugly they appear to us.

Using decimal values means that to move item F between items J and K all you need to do is select the order values for J and K then average them then update F. Two SELECT statements and one UPDATE statement (probably done using serializable isolation to avoid deadlocks).

If you want to see integers rather than fractions in the output then either calculate integers in the client application or use the ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() functions (if your RDBMS includes them).

Comment: how "deep" would this averaging rule allow you to go? it seems to be inverse powers of two, so I think with "double" precision, that would be at most ~53 levels, which is not very many.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/304597/57805) much better. Quoting it entirely:

> Databases are optimized for certain things. Updating lots of rows quickly is one of them.  This becomes especially true when you let the database do its work.
>
> Consider:
>
> ```
> order song
> 1     Happy Birthday
> 2     Beat It
> 3     Never Gonna Give You Up
> 4     Safety Dance
> 5     Imperial March
> ```
>
> And you want to move `Beat It` to the end, you would have two queries:
>
> ```sql
> update table 
>   set order = order - 1
>   where order >= 2 and order <= 5;
>
> update table
>   set order = 5
>   where song = 'Beat It'
> ```
>
> And that's it.  This scales up very well with very large numbers. Try putting a few thousand songs in a hypothetical playlist in your database and see how long it takes to move a song from one location to another.  As these have very standardized forms:
>
> ```sql
> update table 
>   set order = order - 1
>   where order >= ? and order <= ?;
>
> update table
>   set order = ?
>   where song = ?
> ```
>
> You have two prepared statements that you can reuse very efficiently.
>
> This provides some significant advantages - the order of the table is something that you can reason about. The third song has an `order` of 3, always. The only way to guarantee this is to use consecutive integers as the order.  Using pseudo-linked lists or decimal numbers or integers with gaps won't let you guarantee this property; in these cases the only way to get the nth song is to sort the entire table and get the nth record.
>
> And really, this is a lot easier than you think it is. It is simple to figure out what you want to do, to generate the two update statements and for other people to look at those two update statements and realize what is being done.

Answer (score 1):

In my own project, I'm planning to try a solution similar to the decimal number solution, but using byte-arrays instead:

```
def pad(x, x_len, length):
    if x_len >= length:
        return x
    else:
        for _ in range(length - x_len):
            x += b"\x00"
        return x

def order_index(_from, _to, count, length=None):
    assert _from != _to
    assert _from < _to

    if not length:
        from_len = len(_from)
        to_len = len(_to)
        length = max(from_len, to_len)

        _from = pad(_from, from_len, length)
        _to = pad(_to, to_len, length)

    from_int = int.from_bytes(_from, "big")
    to_int = int.from_bytes(_to, "big")
    inc = (to_int - from_int)//(count + 1)
    if not inc:
        length += 1
        _from += b"\x00"
        _to += b"\x00"
        return order_index(_from, _to, count, length)

    return (int.to_bytes(from_int + ((x+1)*inc), length, "big") for x in range(count))
```

```
>>> index = order_index(b"A", b"Z", 24)
>>> [x for x in index]
[b'B', b'C', b'D', b'E', b'F', b'G', b'H', b'I', b'J', b'K', b'L', b'M', b'N', b'O', b'P', b'Q', b'R', b'S', b'T', b'U', b'V', b'W', b'X', b'Y']
>>> 
>>> index = order_index(b"A", b"Z", 25)
>>> [x for x in index]
[b'A\xf6', b'B\xec', b'C\xe2', b'D\xd8', b'E\xce', b'F\xc4', b'G\xba', b'H\xb0', b'I\xa6', b'J\x9c', b'K\x92', b'L\x88', b'M~', b'Nt', b'Oj', b'P`', b'QV', b'RL', b'SB', b'T8', b'U.', b'V$', b'W\x1a', b'X\x10', b'Y\x06']
```

The idea is that you can never run out of possible in-between values because and you just append a `b"\x00"` to the records involved if you need more values. (`int` is unbounded in Python 3, otherwise you'd have to choose a slice of the bytes at the end to compare, the assumption being that, between two adjacent values, the differences would be packed toward the end.)

E.g., say you have two records, `b"\x00"` and `b"\x01"`, and you want a record to go between them. There aren't any available values between `0x00` and `0x01`, so you append `b"\x00"` to both, and now you have a bunch of values between them you can use to insert new values.

```
>>> records = [b"\x00", b"\x01", b"\x02"]
>>> values = [x for x in order_index(records[0], records[1], 3)]
>>> records = records + values
>>> records.sort()
>>> records
[b'\x00', b'\x00@', b'\x00\x80', b'\x00\xc0', b'\x01', b'\x02']
```

The database can easily sort it because everything ends up in lexicographic order. If you delete a record, it's still in order. In my project, I've made `b"\x00"` and `b"\xff"` as `FIRST` and `LAST` records, though, in order to use those as virtual "from" and "to" values to prepend/append new records:

```
>>> records = []
>>> value = next(order_index(FIRST, LAST, 1))
>>> value
b'\x7f'
>>> records.append(value)
>>> value = next(order_index(records[0], LAST, 1))
>>> value
b'\xbf'
>>> records.append(value)
>>> records.sort()
>>> records
[b'\x7f', b'\xbf']
>>> value = next(order_index(FIRST, records[0], 1))
>>> value
b'?'
>>> records.append(value)
>>> records.sort()
>>> records
[b'?', b'\x7f', b'\xbf']
```